# Maintain a stock sheet in google sheets with seperate Inventory and Issuance sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 sheets which are inventory count and issuance count, both of them have sample numbers and their count. I want to maintain a 3rd stock sheet which will show sample number, its inventory count, the issuance count and the stock count. Stock count is just inventory count - issuance count.

The inventory and issuance count sheets will get updated automatically.

The sample numbers might not be arranged in same manner in inventory count and issuance count sheets, moreover some of the samples which might be there in inventory count might not be there in issuance count, so its issuance count in the stock sheet must be 0.

I have pasted the link to a reference sheet similar to my use-case. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

> https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UDlCzA1WDkIWDNoEffihSH2rKegKHciSP1kqp_QJ-kY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place array formulas in the headers that will do what you ask.

All the unique **sample numbers**:

```
={
  "Sample Number";
  SORT(UNIQUE(
    {
      UNIQUE(FILTER(Issuance!A2:A, Issuance!A2:A <> ""));
      UNIQUE(FILTER(Inventory!A2:A, Inventory!A2:A <> ""))
    }
  ))
}
```

[image]

**Inventory Count**:

```
={
  "Inventory Count";
  ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B = "", "", COUNTIF(Inventory!A2:A, B2:B)))
}
```

[image]

**Issuance Count**:

```
={
  "Issuance Count";
  ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B = "", "", COUNTIF(Issuance!A2:A, B2:B)))
}
```

[image]

**Stock**:

```
={
  "Stock";
  ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B = "", "", C2:C - D2:D))
}
```

[image]

Look at you sample sheet, all this is there.